# how to show inbox messages in list view

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show inbox messages in list view. i have tried many way's but seem there is some error ..

can someone tell any different approach to do this .

```
public class Inbox extends ListActivity 
{          
        ArrayList<String> ListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {      
               Uri urisms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
               Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(urisms, null, null ,null,null);
               if(c.moveToFirst())
               {
                             for(int i=0; i < c.getCount(); i++)
                             {   String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
                                   ListItems.add(body);
                                 c.moveToNext();
                             }
                             if(ListItems.isEmpty())
                                 ListItems.add("no messages found !!");
                }
                c.close();
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ListItems);
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setListAdapter(adapter);

        } 
}
```

why this one is not working . ??

Comment: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); call this after oncreate

Comment: where u call layout file?

Comment: you mean 
1.) super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); should be first line in onCreate function ?
2.) super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); should be outside onCreate ?

or

Comment: solved that was the error . calling order of super constructor . thanx.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> ListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {      
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           Uri urisms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
           Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(urisms, null, null ,null,null);
           if(c.moveToFirst())
           {
                         for(int i=0; i < c.getCount(); i++)
                         {   String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
                               ListItems.add(body);
                             c.moveToNext();
                         }
                         if(ListItems.isEmpty())
                             ListItems.add("no messages found !!");
            }
            c.close();
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ListItems);

            setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
```